# Superimposed plots with haskell-chart

Tags: haskell, charts

I am trying to use haskell-chart to draw a histogram with a superimposed density function. Following the examples on the project wiki and the [tests](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/blob/f03be667eccfef4c62c50b93cd4638c82151549d/chart-tests/tests/Test19.hs), I wrote this code:

```
chart = toRenderable $ do
    plot $ fmap histToPlot $ liftEC $ do
        plot_hist_title .= "My histogram"
        plot_hist_bins .= 10
        plot_hist_values .= ([0,1..100] :: Double)
        plot_hist_norm_func .= const id
    plot (line "my curve" myCurve) where 
        myCurve = [zip [0,1..100] (repeat 20)] :: [[(Double, Double)]]
```

This gives a type error, because the histogram plot is `EC (Layout Double Int)` and the curve plot is `EC (Layout Double Double)`. I tried to make the histogram plot into an `EC (Layout Double Double)` by changing `plot_hist_norm_func .= const id` into `const (fromIntegral . id :: Int -> Double)` and providing an instance of `Default (PlotHist x Double)`. The resulted code type-checked but did not draw anything. My question is: *how do I draw a histogram with a curve in haskell-chart?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram package exported everything I needed to make a `Default (PlotHist x Double)` instance like this:

```hs
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Histogram(defaultNormedPlotHist)
instance Default (PlotHist x Double) where
    def = defaultNormedPlotHist
```

Here is the plot I wanted

[image]